# Random function seems to conflicting with bootstrap modal event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The function that seems to be conflicting

```
function makeHeader()
{
            var headerSites = [];
            headerSites.push("Home");
            headerSites.push("index.php");
            headerSites.push("Add exercise");
            headerSites.push("newExercise.php");
            headerSites.push("Calendar");
            headerSites.push("calendar.php");

            var currentPage = location.href.split("/").slice(-1);

            var header = "<div class='navbar-div'>";
            header += "<nav role='navigation' class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>";
            header += "<div class='navbar-header'>";
            header += "<button type='button' data-target='#navbarCollapse' data-toggle='collapse' class='navbar-toggle'>";
            header += "<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>";
            header += "<span class='icon-bar'></span>";
            header += "<span class='icon-bar'></span>";
            header += "<span class='icon-bar'></span>";
            header += "</button";
            header += "<a href='#' class='navbar-brand'>Exercise Site</a>";
            header += "</div>";
            header += "<div id='navbarCollapse' class='collapse navbar-collapse'>";
            header += "<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>";
            for (index = 0; index < headerSites.length; index = index + 2)
            {
                if(currentPage == headerSites[index + 1])
                {

                header += "<li class='active'><a href='" + headerSites[index + 1] + "'>" + headerSites[index] + "</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {

                header += "<li><a href='" + headerSites[index + 1] + "'>" + headerSites[index] + "</a></li>";
                }
            }

            header += "</ul>";
            header += "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
            if(currentPage == "userInfo.php")
            {
                header += "<li class='active'><a href='userInfo.php'>";
            }
            else
            {
            header += "<li><a href='userInfo.php'>";
            }
            header += readCookie('username');
            header += "</a></li></ul></div></nav></div><br><br>";
            document.body.innerHTML = header + document.body.innerHTML;

}
```

I am calling this function with window.onload

```
window.onload=function(){

            makeHeader();
```

The modal function is here

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);  // Button that triggered the modal
        var titleData = button.data('title'); // Extract value from data-* attributes
        $(this).find('.dateVal').attr("value", titleData);
                });

});
```

It works fine if I comment out makeHeader(); but with the function running the event doesn't seem to ever be called I've thrown in alert("error"); to check and it never triggers

Comment: Anything in your debugger-console?

Comment: Might be due to re-assigning innerHTML onload when the modal code ran on document ready. Have you tried running the modal code after the header is done?

Comment: @gillesc looks like that fixed things.